# Deformations on back of the head when trying to rotate rig

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I'm weight painting my model and I am getting weird deformations on the back of the head. I can't figure out how I should weight paint in order to get the back of the head to follow the face when turning.

[image]

[image]

The file is located here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WajpFseBrH8aKv4AlK9S-y8q88ELArbA/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where are the bones that are supposed to weigh on the mesh?

Comment: Bones for the back of the head? i wasn't sure if i needed them. I assumed i could just weight paint the back of the head to certain face bones. Does the back of the head on this model need extra bones?

Comment: I mean in what layer are they? You need to find where they are, then check the influence on this part of your mesh

Comment: @moonboots apologies, i'm still a little confused. This is my first time attempting to rig. Here is an image of where the bones are in the head: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jEdKfGKIvVQhtrz-n1vt6AQi17sl4ECS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what you could is enable trnasparency with alt Z, select all this part of your mesh (back of the head), in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, on the right of the vertex group list, click on the dropdown menu and choose Remove From All Groups, then in Weight Paint mode, assign this part to the bone that is supposed to move it

Comment: @moonboots i did what you said and attached the mesh to the temples and it moved fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is enable transparency with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>, select all this part of your mesh (back of the head), in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, on the right of the vertex group list, click on the dropdown menu and choose *Remove From All Groups*, then in *Weight Paint* mode, assign this part to the bone that is supposed to move it.